# Showing Syntax Error while try to output the dictionary or a list value

Tags: python

I am a amature in Python,using the python33 version.The problem i am facing while i want to get output of a list of dictionary just like that.

```
dict = {'name':'Tanvir','Position':'Programmer'};
print dict['name'];
```

if i run the code then there showing a syntax error.same thing is happening for the list also.
Please help me to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dict` is a builtin. You normally shouldn't replace it. Choose a different name for your `dict`

Comment: Also, Python doesn't need semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `print` is a function, so you need `print(dict[name])`.  You also don't need the semicolons.  You also need to read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to learn the basics first.